# WooCommerce - get product by title?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How can you get a product by it's name? I know you can do it by ID and SKU, but for my current situation I need to grab a product by its title. I've been looking it up and can't seem to find the function.

My function occurs on the single product page, but the product I need to get data from WILL NOT be the current product that the user is looking at. Instead it will have the same name as the current product, just ending with a different symbol. (the product the user will be looking at ends with "-r" and the one I need to search for ends with "-$$$")

So far in my Functions.php:

```
  function fill_refurbished_addon_selectbox(){
    //get id of current product
    global $product;    
    $id= $product->get_id();
    //get name of product
    $currentName = get_the_title($id);
    //remove -r, add -$$$ and store in var
    $searchFor = substr($currentName, 0, -2) . "-$$$";
    echo $searchFor;    
    //find $$$ product by title
    $coreCharge = ***GET PRODUCT BY TITLE ($searchFOr)***;
    //get price of $$$ product, store in var

    //populate dropbox

}
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'fill_refurbished_addon_selectbox', 20);
```

The reason is, I need to fill a select box with info from the -$$$ product.

Answer (score 13):

please try this

```
$product = get_page_by_title( 'Product Title', OBJECT, 'product' );
```

get_page_by_title retrieves a post given its title. If more than one post uses the same title, the post with the smallest ID will be returned.

syntax:-  `get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output, $post_type );`

In wordpress 6.2 this function is deprecated

instead you can use it's [definition](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) with little bit of change

```
function get_page_by_title(string $name, string $post_type = "post") {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        "post_type" => $post_type,
        "name" => $name
    ]);

    return $query->have_posts() ? reset($query->posts) : null;
}
```

now call `get_page_by_title(<product_name>, 'product')`

or if you want to make it WooCommerce specific, you can create a wrapper called

```
function get_product_by_title($productTitle) {
    return get_page_by_title($productTitle, 'product')
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I wound up just grabbing it by SKU since it is the same as the title.

Comment: @SebG if it is solution to your question, consider accepting it as answer too, that will be helpful to others . or if you have a better answer, please consider posting that.I would like to learn .

Comment: Give only 1 product :(

Comment: @mishanon that was the expected behaviour, check question and also codex, you will get better idea.

Comment: Be aware: As of WordPress 6.2, the function `get_page_by_title()` is **deprecated**.

Comment: @AlexSpataru I have updated my answer, hope that will be helpful.